# Clear HTML5 local storage on a specific page

Tags: google-chrome, html5, local-storage

Is it possible to clear HTML5 local storage on a specific web page? I was editing a Javascript demo on http://jsfiddle.net, and I re-arranged the windows in such a way that one of them became impossible to resize. Is it possible to clear local storage on a specific page in this case?

Comment: use the browser's console to change localStorage's contents. it is just a javascript object like any other.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Chrome now provides an option to clear Local Storage of a specific site. For this, enter this in the Omnibox

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

Now, you can type the site name, select Local storage and click on Remove to clear local storage for the site

[image]

Comment: If only it didn't crash every time I try to search / delete something there...

Comment: Haha yes, same here, I had to look for the item manually through the list @Selrond

Comment: Seemed to work OK for me...

Comment: Notably, this won't work on Android...

Answer (score 63):

While Chrome does not provide a UI for clearing localStorage, there is an API that will either clear a specific key or the entire localStorage object on a website.

```
//Clears the value of MyKey
window.localStorage.removeItem("MyKey");

//Clears all the local storage data
window.localStorage.clear();
```

Every Chrome browser, by default, has the JavaScript console installed. So an alternative method, and perhaps the easiest way, to clear localStorage is to right click on the page, click "Inspect Element", then click the "Console" tab. When the console opens, type the following JavaScript, and press enter:

```
window.localStorage.clear()
```

Once done, localStorage will be cleared. Note that this affects all web pages on a single domain, so if you clear localStorage for jsfiddle.net/index.html (assuming that's the page you're on), then it clears it for all other pages on that site.  See [HTML5Goodies - A Peek into Local Data Storage in HTML 5](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/a-peek-into-local-data-storage-in-html-5.html#fbid=m6K7mMse3WQ) for more information.

Answer (score 10):

Chrome does not yet provide an interface to manage HTML5 local-storage, so to delete local-storage in Chrome, you will need to either manually search for and delete the file in the `Local Storage` sub-directory in the [User Data](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory). You can find it by looking for a file that contains the domain name.

You can also use the *Delete cookies and other site and plug-in data* entry in the *Clear browsing data* dialog (`chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>), however it does not give you fine-grained control at the site level.

For the record, jsfiddle.net does not use local-storage for its frames, it uses standard cookies which you can delete in `chrome://chrome/settings/cookies`. Just type `jsf` in the edit box, then click the `window_sizes` cookie, then the `[Remove]` button. To delete all cookies at `jsfiddle.net`, just click the `jsfiddle` entry (not any spefcific cookie), and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Think this answer is out of date. On Win 7 in chrome dev panel, on the resources tab you can right click individual local storage entries for a specific site and delete them. Seems to be one at a time, but still works. Chrome Version: 35.0.1916.114

Answer (score 8):

You can also clear it through the console in the developer window with the command `localStorage.clear()`:

[image]

Comment: Is `undefined` an expected response?

Comment: yes, no problem about that.it removes storage nicely :) @WeishiZeng

Answer (score 6):

If you have [Chrome **Developer Tools**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) you can see or change the localStorage values

- <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
- Application
- Storage
- Local Storage

It is organized by domain. (localStorage is specific to a domain, not a page.)

[image]

Highlight the key/value pairs and click **X** if you want to delete them.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot yet comment, but the accepted answer is not 100% accurate anymore since the newest Chrome update. Chrome has got a new material look for all of the settings; and the link to clear all local storage for a specified host is now slightly different:

```
chrome://settings/siteData
```

Comment: it's `chrome://settings/siteData`

Answer (score 1):

**The answer** `chrome://settings/siteData` **did not work for me**

This is what works for me in Chrome version 61 :

1. `chrome://settings/content/cookies`
2. scroll down to *All cookies and site data*, and in the "Search cookies" input enter "localhost"
3. then click *Remove all shown* , or hit the delete button

This clears **not just cookies** but also *local storage* and your *local databases* too

Comment: Step 2 points there...

Comment: Note on Edge Chromium that you can do this with `edge://` prefix instead of `chrome://` prefix, but I noticed that it leaves Local Storage intact for Edge Chromium Extensions, which is good because otherwise it might break some of the reserved settings you may have had in your extensions.

Answer (score 1):

**Clear Local Storage extension**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-local-storage/adilpdccjldjgnipbjmnlgljhlbhkifb/related?hl=en

Then you can just hit Ctrl + Shift + L then Enter and it clears local storage for the current page, and reloads the page.

A shortcut for this is a must when developing certain kinds of websites, so if Chrome won't provide one, an extension is justified.

As mentioned on the documentation, cookies are not cleared, only local storage.