# how to change user for offline google docs access

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-docs

When attempting to see if a doc is available offline clicking the "all changes saved to drive" to check for status icon says:

"Looks like you're offline. This document cannot be edited without internet connectivity because another user (xxx@gmail.com) has already enabled offline access on this computer."

I did have several google accounts logged in at the time, including myself and "xxx"

I logged xxx out but still it complains.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

This seemed to work.

Log out the "offending" user (basically google.com -> logout all top right).

Login as the new user.

Clear all "data" for docs.google.com (chrome://settings/siteData?searchSubpage=docs.google.com [ref](https://superuser.com/questions/519628/clear-html5-local-storage-on-a-specific-page) )

open the google doc you'd like to have offline.

the status icon inside the doc will say "This document is not ready for offline use" then open drive.google.com in a different tab.  Somehow just the process of opening drive.google.com starts the sync process flowing again.

A little popup will soon appear "reload this doc to enable offline access" within the google doc.  Reload google doc.

Comment: Thanks. A similar solution worked for me under Brave 1.28.* and Ubuntu 20.10, whereas I just delleted entries under `brave://settings/siteData` that were related to `*.google.com*` so colab, drive, calendar etc. Not sure all were needed but just in case...
The only bummer was having to logout from 8+ google accounts and logging back in to all of them, but nothing terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Appears other options: login to that user and go to drive.google.com -> settings, de-select sync.

Or create a new chrome "profile" and use that instead from now on.

ref: https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-google-docs-offline-not-working/