# Is there a shortcut in chrome to clear the local storage with a hotkey?

Tags: google-chrome

It's a bit of a pain to always have to go into dev tools, application, right click delete the key

Comment: Is this more convenient? https://superuser.com/a/655198/48078

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear HTML5 local storage on a specific page](https://superuser.com/questions/519628/clear-html5-local-storage-on-a-specific-page)